# How to use cellStyleClassNames for designing table cells

Tags: abap, webdynpro

Unfortunately I did not find any documentation about the proper use of **cellStyleClassNames** attribute for designing table color in SAP Webdyn Pro ABAP.

The SAP Example WDR_TEST_CUSTOM_STYLES has a lot of code in the methods and is tied to various elements in the context.

So how to simply assign a certain cell, row or column a custom style?

Answer (score 0):

Using of *cellStyleClassNames* property is similar to using *styleClassName* which example you can find [here](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/57/fa8b41bce2a609e10000000a155106/content.htm). Your actions should be like these:

1. Create context attribute of type *WDR_CELL_STYLE_CLASS_NAME* to store your styles, and bind it to *cellStyleClassNames* attribute of your table.
2. Create table of cell styles which have following properties: *name* of type `string`, *element_type* of type `WDY_MD_UI_ELEMENT_DEF_NAME` and *style_properties* of type `string` and store it in context node.
3. Fill the table with styles with necessary properties.
4. Create supplementary table for *assignment* certain style to certain cell. It should have attributes *row_index* of type `WDR_CELL_STYLE_CLASS_NAME-ROW_INDEX`, *column_id* of type `WDR_CELL_STYLE_CLASS_NAME-COLUMN_ID` and *style_class_name* of type `WDR_CELL_STYLE_CLASS_NAME-STYLE_CLASS_NAME`
5. Finally you should bind the above table to your attribute from p.1